# How to delete .DS_Store using unlink

Tags: php, macos

I've created a simple function to delete all the files inside a folder and the folder itself.

```
function fn_delete_dir($dir)
{
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $dir = rtrim($dir, '/') . '/'; // add slash to end of string
        $files = glob($dir . '*', GLOB_MARK);

        foreach ($files as $vfile) {
            if (is_dir($vfile)) {
                fn_delete_dir($vfile);
            } else {
                unlink($vfile);
            }
        }

        rmdir($dir);

        return 1;
    }
}


$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/page/videography/images/videos/thumbs';

if (fn_delete_dir($dir)) {
    echo 'all files deleted';
} else {
    echo 'deletion failed';
}
```

This use to work on my windows machine. Since I switched to a Mac, this function fails with the msg

```
Warning: rmdir(/Users/xxx/Sites/page/videography/images/videos/thumbs/): Directory not empty in /Users/xxx/Sites/[age/testing.php on line 18
```

I did a scandir just to check if there are hidden files, and I got the following

```
   Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => .DS_Store
    [3] => thumbs
)
```

I'm guessing that the problem is `.DS_Store` and/or `thumbs`

So, the question is how do I delete those hidden files?

Comment: `$files = glob()` is not the best option to enumerate all the files in a directory. Use [`opendir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir)/`readdir()`/`closedir()` or the [`Directory` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directory.php) (use [`dir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php) to create an instance of `Directory`).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @axiac, I was able re-create the function using opendir() / readdir() / closedir()

This function is able to delete files like `thumbs` `.DS_Store`...

```
function fn_delete_dir($dir)
{
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $dir = rtrim($dir, '/') . '/'; // add slash to end of string

        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    if (is_dir($dir . $file)) {
                        fn_delete_dir($dir . $file);
                    } else {
                        unlink($dir . $file);
                    }
                }
            }

            closedir($dh);
            rmdir($dir . $file);

            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```